# Excluding svn directory when deploying to Tomcat in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, maven, tomcat

I have a Java project which is separated into 23 sub-projects that are all checked into a subversion repository. When they are checked out (not using the Eclipse SVN tool) there's a `.svn` directory on several levels of each sub-project. Then I run `mvn eclipse:clean eclipse:eclipse` on the whole thing (as these are Maven projects) I can import them into Eclipse and work there. So far, so good.

Here's the problem: When I deploy the project to Tomcat in Eclipse (oh yes, it's a web project) the `.svn` directories are also deployed. I can circumvent this by adding Resource filters in Eclipse (*project properties -> Resource -> Resource Filters -> Add -> Exclude all, Files and folders, All children (recursive), Project Relative Path matches ***/.svn) but every time I recreate the projects with maven (which I have to do ever so often) I have to recreate the filters for each of the 23 projects. Is there a better method to exclude resources for the tomcat deployment?

Note: I'm using

- Java 1.6,
- Eclipse Juno,
- Tortoise SVN 1.7.6 (which comes with Subversion 1.7.4),
- Maven 3.0.3 and
- Tomcat 7.0.35

I am, sadly, not allowed to update anything. An ideal solution for me would be something like a global resource filter in Eclipse or some setting which would make Maven create Eclipse projects with such resource filters already set.

Comment: Why is this a problem? Presumably your final Maven artifact is a WAR. Why do the extra SVN folders cause problems with Tomcat?

Comment: The problem is, that the total size of those `.svn` files is about 8 - 10 MB and due to the antivirus software (which I can't tweek) the deployment process takes ages as it is. So ignoring the overhead can make the difference between a few minutes of waiting and a few minutes of productivity each time I deploy - which is several times a day. And Eclipse doesn't deploy it as a WAR but as a browsable folder - containing `.svn` directories.

Comment: it's just a workaround but, do you tried export the project like a .war file (using eclipse export utility , not the maven task) and deploy it in tomcat? the war file exported has the .svn folders?

Comment: @Grubhart: If exported like that the WAR file does not have the `.svn` folders, no. It's not deployed to Tomcat either of course, but maybe there's a way to use this same mechanism?

Comment: Have you tried the WTP Tomcat option 'Serve modules without publishing'?

Comment: @MarcelStör: I hadn't and doing so is a good idea - it saves me even more time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have the option to change the `pom.xml`, then I would expect that you can use [sourceExcludes](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/eclipse-mojo.html#sourceExcludes). That would be the automated version of your manual handlings.
There's also an example with svn files:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/specifying-source-path-inclusions-and-exclusions.html

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I knew there had to be some simple way of doing this. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use latest svn client - it will create only one .svn folder at parent folder.

Also, latest eclipse can import maven project without `mvn eclipse:eclipse`.

Comment: I'd love to, but sadly I can't choose - this is a work project and every tiny piece of software used has to be cleared by a whole bunch of people; let's just say we're still using Windows XP, Java 1.6 and IE 8. :-(